Building a drywell for the small cabin
We have a small cabin in the woods that we use on weekends. Since there’s no sewage system nearby, we rely on a camping toilet (Porta Potty), which works well for us.
However, we’d like to set up a dry well to handle the graywater from our shower (approximately 10 liters per day) and dishwashing (about 5 liters per day). While this isn’t heavily contaminated water, it’s not as clean as rainwater either.
Additionally, because the cabin is located in a particularly rainy region, we’d like to manage the rainwater runoff to keep the foundation dry, as it isn’t very deep.
After doing some research, I found two possible solutions for the dry well: one with a container and one without. Other than increased water storage capacity, what are the key differences between these two designs? Are there any important considerations or best practices I should keep in mind when building a small dry well?
Thank you!


Step zero, find out what's legal in the location. In many locations you don't get to invent your own solution.

We are in France and this is so small building so I am not obliged to follow any rules as far as I do not endanger the neighbour.

I'm not sure this sort of bushcraft qualifies as home improvement here. Please see the [help] and take the [tour].

This isn't really a discussion forum.

First, don't combine a "greywater" dry well with your additional goal of taking roof/gutter water (which is clean rainwater) away from the building. Preferably take the roof runoff somewhere far way from the greywater dry well so it has minimal impact on that. If you want the roof runoff in a dry well as well, you  can have one, or it can just exit on the surface.
How much fuss you need to go to (or how much storage capacity you need for your dry well to work) depends on the percolation of the soil you're installing the dry well into.
That can be formally assessed by a percolation test, which is measuring how fast a hole dug in the ground and filled with water drains that water. In clay soils, that takes a very long time. In gravel soils, it can be difficult to get water into the hole fast enough to get it full. For a permitted septic waste system it typically needs to be done by an engineer following prescribed procedures.
For an installation not requiring a permit, you can dig a hole and fill it yourself, and observe how it behaves. If you make a hole the size of a typical 20l/5 gallon Bucket and it drains in an hour or less, you'd likely be fine at your proposed 15L/day output. If the hole has standing water the next day, you might need a substantially larger well to handle the water.
The primary advantage of using a well with a porous/perforated bucket, drum, or brick liner is that it's feasible to clean it out in the event that grease from kitchen waste and/or hair from shower waste clogs things up. If the well is full of rocks and it clogs up, you either dig the rocks out to wash them or abandon it and make a new well. You do need a sturdy cover so as not to make a hazard in the yard with a lined/open well.
Particularly if the soil drains slowly, it may be worth making two wells for greywater and providing a valve to switch which one is in use at any time.
